# Declare php variables for INSERT query in MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, sql

How to declare php variables that will consist the mysql query columns and values properly? The thing is obviously in quotations, I tried several combination witn no success.

This is the query declared in php:

```
$query = "INSERT INTO table1(pt1, pt2, pt3, pt4, pt5, pt6, pt7, pt8) VALUES ('$q[1]','$q[2]','$q[3]','$q[4]','$q[5]','$q[6]','$q[7]','$q[8]')";
```

This is my wrong variables in php: (two wrong approaches)

```
$pt_all = pt1, pt2, pt3, pt4, pt5, pt6, pt7, pt8;

for($i=1;$i<9;$i++) {
    $q_all .= '$q[$i]',;
}
```

This is made in order to place the holder variables into the sql query in php:

```
$query = "INSERT INTO table1($pt_all) VALUES ($q_all)";
```

And make it easier and shorter. Is there maybe other better technique?

Comment: The best technique to use is prepared/parameterized queries, so you can fundamentally separate the data from the command, keeping you nice and secure.  I'd tell you how to do that, but you don't mention what database API you're using.  Consider using PDO or similar.

Comment: If you want to make a comma separated list of elements, try using `implode()`. Here's the documentation: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php

Comment: I didn't use PDO, I used MySQL - it is Joomla DBO connection to database

Comment: Ever figure this out?

Answer (score 0):

FIrst of all, **do not use mysql_* functions**, since those are deprecated. Use mysqli_* or PDO. That said, you probably need something like this:

```
$fields = "pt".join(", pt",array_keys($q)); //pt1, pt2, pt3, ..
$values = "'".join("','",array_values($q))."'"; //values

echo "INSERT INTO ({$fields}) VALUES ({$values})";
```

Obviously, you will need to adjust this to fit your requirements, but this should give you good sense on array manipulation.

Answer (score 0):

start with an associative array. As an example, I'll use fruit..

```
$array = array("banana" => "yellow", "apple" => "red", "kiwi" => "green");
```

Go through and make the strings "banana, apple, kiwi" and "yellow, red, green"

```
$fields = array();
$values = array();
foreach($array as $key => $val){
    $fields[] = $key;
    $values[] = $val;
}
```

Now concatenate into a string to be used as SQL

```
$query = 'INSERT INTO table1("'.implode('", "', $fields).'") ';
$query .= 'VALUES ("'.implode('", "', $values).'");';
echo $query; // "INSERT INTO table1("banana", "apple", "kiwi") VALUES ("yellow", "red", "green");
```

Hope that's what you're looking for.